# JS Form Validation incomplete

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm supposed to validate a form. There are a few things that do not work properly.

1) The background color does not change when the field is invalid.

2) It says an email is invalid even if you enter a correct one. I need to validate if there is an '@' and '.XX' or '.XXX' where X is a valid alphabetic character.

3) When the user chooses 'Other' from the drop-down menu, the empty field does not pop up.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

HTML

```js
document.getElementById("mysub").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var message = document.getElementById("msg").value;

  if (firstname == "" || firstname == " ") {
    alert("Please fill out your first name");
    document.getElementById("fname").style.backgroundColor = "d64161";
  }

  if (lastname == "" || lastname == " ") {
    alert("Please fill out your last name");
    document.getElementById("lname").style.backgroundColor = "d64161";
  }

  if (email == "" || email == " ") {
    alert("Please fill out your email");
    document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "d64161";
  }
  if (!email.includes("@")) {
    alert("Invalid email");
  }
  if (!email.includes(".com") || !email.includes(".ca")) {
    alert("Invalid email")
  }

  if (message == "" || message == " ") {
    alert("Please enter a message");
    document.getElementById("msg").style.backgroundColor = "d64161";
  }
})

function test() {
  if (document.getElementById('options').value == 'other') {
    document.getElementById('emptyfield').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('emptyfield').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <legend>
      Contact information
    </legend>

    *First Name:
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
    <br><br> Middle/Initial:
    <input type="text" name="middle" maxLength="2" id="mname">
    <br><br> *Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
    <br><br> *Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <br><br> Phone:
    <input type="number" name="number" id="num">

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>

    <legend>
      Message
    </legend>

    *Reason
    <select id="options" name="state" onclick='test()'>
                    <option value="Information">Infor reques</option>
                    <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option> 
          </select>
    <input type="text" id="emptyfield" name="extra" style="display: none">

    <br><br> *Message <br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5" id="msg"></textarea>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="mysub">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Hexadecimal colors require `#` in front of them.

Comment: You’re not preventing form submission when the form is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `preventDefault`, so whenever there are problems, the form gets submitted anyway. You're also not setting the colors properly; hex colors require a `#` before them.

Try making your code more DRY, reducing the amount you have to repeat similar code, and ensuring that the user only ever gets one alert, rather than many (alerts are very user-unfriendly):

```js
document.getElementById("mysub").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  const firstname = document.getElementById("fname");
  const lastname = document.getElementById("lname");
  const email = document.getElementById("email");
  const message = document.getElementById("msg");

  const failingFields = [];

  if (firstname.value.trim() === '') failingFields.push([firstname, 'Please enter a first name']);
  if (lastname.value.trim() === '') failingFields.push([lastname, 'Please enter a last name']);
  const emailValue = email.value;
  if (emailValue.trim() === '' || !emailValue.includes('@') || (!emailValue.includes('.com') && !emailValue.includes('.ca'))) failingFields.push([email, 'Please enter a valid email']);
  if (message.value.trim() === '') failingFields.push([message, 'Please enter a message']);
  if (failingFields.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errorMessage = failingFields.map(failingField => failingField[1]).join('\n');
    failingFields.forEach(failingField => failingField[0].style.backgroundColor = '#d64161');
    alert(errorMessage);
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <legend>
      Contact information
    </legend>

    *First Name:
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
    <br><br> Middle/Initial:
    <input type="text" name="middle" maxLength="2" id="mname">
    <br><br> *Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
    <br><br> *Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <br><br> Phone:
    <input type="number" name="number" id="num">

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>

    <legend>
      Message
    </legend>

    *Reason
    <select id="options" name="state" onclick='test()'>
                    <option value="Information">Infor reques</option>
                    <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option> 
          </select>
    <input type="text" id="emptyfield" name="extra" style="display: none">

    <br><br> *Message <br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5" id="msg"></textarea>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="mysub">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help :)